# How can you process an input element from a form before saving it to a model with django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a text input that is a comma separated list of items. These items are in a many-to-many relationship with another model.  I want to process that string of items and split them up by the delimited comma so that I have a list of them to save to the database.  Is there a way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. You can create custom field that will follow needed behavior https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/. Also you can overwrite save() methods for you model or form and do all logic where.

Answer (score 0):

[Cleaning and Validating Fields that Depend On Each Other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) contains an example of how to override either the `clean_<fieldname>` or `to_python` methods in a `modelForm` to turn a comma-separated string of email addresses in an array.

Comment: This seems to be close, but it doesn't save the items to the database when save() is called on the modelForm...